# Read Process Memory in C#

Tags: c#, memory

I want to read process memory on some game, this is java game and run on KEmulator which is Java application Emulator. In this point i already get the process id from the window and the Modules from Process. But i don't found the pointer showed in cheat engine ("jvm.dll").

This is my code :

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcesses();
        Process procs = null;

        foreach (Process proc in p) {
            if (proc.MainWindowTitle == "KEmulator Lite v0.9.8") 
            {
                procs = proc;
                break;
            }
        }

        IntPtr addr = (IntPtr)0;
        foreach (ProcessModule pm in procs.Modules) {
            Debug.WriteLine(pm.ModuleName)
            if(pm.ModuleName == "jvm.dll")
                {
                addr = pm.BaseAddress;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(addr)
```

This is the pointer showed in cheat engine

[image: Pointer on cheat engine]

This is the module i got from the Process

[image: The modules i get from processId]